# asp.net c# allowing users to search string using multiple terms

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, search-engine

I am trying to add a search feature to my application which will allow someone to enter several words and search for those in my data.
Doing single words and phrases is simple:

```
if (x.Title.ToUpper().Contains(tbSearch.Text.ToUpper()) || x.Description.ToUpper().Contains(tbSearch.Text.ToUpper()))
```

BUT how do I work out if someone entered a search for "red car" and the title was "the car that is red"? I know I could split on SPACE and then search for each term but this seems over complicated and I would also need to strip out non word characters.

I've been looking at using RegExes but am not sure if it would search for items in order or any order.

I guess I'm trying to basically create a simple google search in my application.

Comment: You should use a Full Text Search Engine rather than using .net for this. This is a solved hard problem and you will be reinventing the square wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a proper search engine such as Lucene? The StandardAnalyzer in Lucene uses the StandardTokenizer, which takes care of (some) special characters, when tokenizing. It would for example split "red-car" into the tokens "red car", thereby "removing" special characters.

In order to search in multiple fields in a Lucene index, you could use the MultiFieldQueryParser.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
    public static bool HasWordsContaining(this string searchCriteria, string toFilter)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(string.Format("^{0}| {0}", Regex.Escape(toFilter)), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        return regex.IsMatch(searchCriteria);
    }
```

Usage:

```
someList.Where(x=>x.Name.HasWordsContaining(searchedText)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use CONTAINSTABLE for this. You can use a SPROC and pass in the search string.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO

SELECT 
    KEY_TBL.RANK, 
    FT_TBL.Description
FROM 
    Production.ProductDescription AS FT_TBL 
INNER JOIN
FREETEXTTABLE
    (
    Production.ProductDescription, 
    Description,
    'perfect all-around bike'
    ) AS KEY_TBL
 ON FT_TBL.ProductDescriptionID = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
 ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC
 GO
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx